# Links dinâmicos no Ionic, com inAppBrowser

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

Estou desenvolvendo um app com Ionic, que consome uma API externa (json). Para fazer links que abram no navegador nativo, adicionei o plugin inAppBrowser e funcionou.

A questão é que alguns links são dinâmicos, construídos com variáveis da API, no  caso "url" e "id", da seguinte forma:

```
<button id="encontrar-button1" class="button button-balanced  button-block icon-left ion-plus-circled" onclick="window.open('http://www.site.com/pagina/{{ url }}/{{ id }}/', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">Link</button>
```

Não funciona... me parece que o Angular descarta as variáveis. Como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente você não pode utilizar diretivas onClick nesse caso, senão as variáveis não vão ser traduzidas pelo angular.
E outro, não use o objeto window diretamente nos seus links. Crie um método no seu controller para isso.

Exemplificando, deixe assim no seu html:

```
<button id="encontrar-button1" ng-click="openURL('http://www.site.com/pagina/{{ url }}/{{ id }}/')" class="button button-balanced  button-block icon-left ion-plus-circled">Link</button>
```

E no controller respectivo crie um método dessa forma:

```
$scope.openURL = function(url){
    window.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes');
}
```